Obtener el dato de una lista con linq
Necesito pasar a la vista a través de un ViewData el último número de transacción del diario mayor contable desde una .ToListAsync()
En asientoController tengo el siguiente código:
    public async Task<IActionResult> Guardar()
    {

        ViewData["ultimoAsiento"] = new AsientoAdmin().UltimoAsiento();
        ViewData["CuentasDetalle"] = new SelectList(await new AsientoAdmin().ListarCuentasDetalle(), "NroCuenta", "NombreCuenta");
        ViewBag.mensaje = "";
        return View();
    }

En mi clase asientoAdmin, tengo lo siguiente:
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DiarioMayor>> UltimoAsiento()
    {
        using (ContabilidadIBPCContext contexto = new ContabilidadIBPCContext())
        {
            var ultimoAsiento = await contexto.DiarioMayors.OrderByDescending(n=>n.NumTransaccion).ToListAsync();

            var objeto = ultimoAsiento.FirstOrDefault();
            int num = 0;

            if (objeto != null)
            {
                num = (int)objeto.NumTransaccion;
            }
            return num; **En esta parte me sale error : "No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'int' en 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ContabilidadIBPCver2.Models.DiarioMayor>'" 
        }
    }


En la declaración de la función indicas el tipo de retorno
public async Task<IEnumerable<DiarioMayor>> UltimoAsiento()

Con eso dices que es del tipo Task que "envuelve" un IEnumerable<DiarioMayor>, pero tu quieres que sea un int, entonces colocas:
public async Task<int> UltimoAsiento()
{
   //etc
}

Luego debes recordar que estas retornando Task<int>``, entonces cuando llamas la función para quedartarte con un int(en lugar de unTask) debes usar await`
ViewData["ultimoAsiento"] = await (new AsientoAdmin()).UltimoAsiento();

